# post function of jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am running this code :

```
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com/me',{},
     function(msg){
     console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
);
```

and I am only getting `Data Saved :` as output in firebug nothig else is coming and call to the url is also not showing why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't post to another domain (or protocol, or port).  More specifically, you *can* but you can't see the response that comes back for security reasons.  [This is part of the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) browsers implement to keep your data from being posted/exploited on remote domains that *aren't* the same as the page you went to.

Picture for example I loaded http://www.yoursite.com and it tried to repeatedly post (as *me* remember) to https://www.mybank.com, using my stored cookies, etc...you see how you *really* wouldn't want that to happen...that's why it's disallowed and the response you get back will be `null` instead of actually seeing the content.

In this case you're looking for one of their API calls using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) (`callback=?` on the URL in jQuery), which works by creating a `<script>` tag...an entirely different thing altogether.  In your case you're looking for something like this:

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/me?callback=?', function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
});
```

Though, that's not a valid API call by itself (e.g. [you need an access token at least](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ng7u8/)), you'll need to use [the method you're actually looking for](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) instead.

---

Bit of a tangent, but since this is so misunderstood, let's take another more popular example to illustrate the dangers *if* this was allowed.  Think about all those services you stay logged into, Facebook, Twitter, etc.  This is *another* facet of the same origin policy, not allowing your cookies, etc to be used is you *do* try and post...why is this?  If my page could just post to Facebook or Twitter already logged in as you, man I could easily broadcast whatever message I wanted...you can see how this would be useful....and *immediately* used for evil as well.

Comment: @Rahul - updated to show how this is done...though I'm not sure what data you're after, so you'll need to call the appropriate URL for that method, I added a link to their API where you can find the URL for the API method you're after :)

Comment: @Nick cool face book api work with getjson :) , but my own server api didn't work ,is it necessary to be https ?

Comment: @Rahul - I'm not familiar what the restrictions are on the FB side, admittedly I only use it for questions here...you'll need to see what error you're getting like I have in the demo above, [click here to see](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ng7u8/).

Comment: @Rahul - I just re-read your comment - "but my own server api didn't work", so you're *not* hitting facebook, but a completely different URL that's *your* server?

Comment: Yes at my server there is an api which in browsers address bar gives the json. but when i run through getjson function it says that page not found , and showing red color in firebug , why so this ?

Comment: @Rahul - It sounds like your URL is not correct (or the server is blocking the request) - when it is correct, make sure you support serving JSONP to the user, normal JSON without the wrapper won't work for cross-domain.

Comment: @Nick If i want to call the delete action of my rest api , what i had tried is , i had called the ajax function by passing type:'DELETE' but it is not working ,Please help how it will be done ?